# angular2 - Get DOM element of inner component in outer component's controller?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Example:

*outer.html*

```
<div *ngFor="let x of y; let i = index">
        <inner-c></inner-c>
</div>
```

*inner-c.html*

```
<div #bar>
    <div class="row no-gutters mt-3 mb-3 ml-5 mr-5">
        foo
    </div>
</div>
```

How to get access to `#bar` DOM element list in `outer.component.ts` controller? Is that possible?

I tried

`@ContentChildren('bar') inputElems: QueryList<ElementRef>;` and `@ViewChildren('bar') inputElems: QueryList<ElementRef>;`

in  `outer.component.ts` but those return an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can directly access the elements from other components. You could however set up an event emitter in the child component to emit the `ElementRef` of the child element. Try the following

inner-c.component.ts

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'inner-c',
  templateUrl: './inner-c.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inner-c.component.css']
})
export class InnerCComponent {
  @Output() childElement = new EventEmitter();
  @ViewChild('bar')
  set viewChild(list: ElementRef){
    this.childElement.emit(list);
  }

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

inner-c.component.html

```html
<div #bar>
  <div class="row no-gutters mt-3 mb-3 ml-5 mr-5">
    foo
  </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```js
export class AppComponent {
  y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

  childElement(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<div *ngFor="let x of y; let i = index">
  <inner-c (childElement)="childElement($event)"></inner-c>
</div>
```